# Will landmines affect planes?

Tags: battlefield-1942

I know grenades, X-packs, and anti-aircraft guns affect planes' health, but would a plane running over (or near) a landmine blow it up?

Comment: Yes, when messing around with friends before we've parachuted onto their carrier and mined the runway. As soon as they take a plane they run over the mine and explode. I don't know if they flew very low over the ground where a mine is if it would set it off though.

Comment: Okay - I seemed to remember being able to toss mines in front of and behind a plane's wheels that would blow up on takeoff, but I wasn't sure. Still interested to know it a plane flying low over a mine would set it off :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, landmines affect planes. As long as they roll physically on it, or it lands on them while they're moving. Meaning if you can hop on a plane just before liftoff, and toss a mine on it while it is in the air, the mine should explode. Bounce or speed of plane may make the mine fall off.

http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Anti-Tank_Mine#Battlefield_1942